# Debugging... Unable to load native library

Tags: debugging, android-ndk

I'm fairly new to android development and it appears that I have a fairly classic exceptions...

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oneloop.Rb/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.oneloop.Rb-1/libRb.so
E/AndroidRuntime( 2119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
```

Most answers that I have seen include setting hasCode to true or making sure to include app_dummy - neither of which resolves my problem.  Additionally, I've confirmed (by converting to zip and exploring) that my compiled apk includes lib/armeabi-v7a/libRb.so.

I've been converting a good size framework (numerous static libraries, opengl, and prebuilt middleware libs) over to android - so my obvious inclination is that I have some sort of incompatibility between the libraries and my SO.  The problem is that logcat doesn't provide information on why the library failed.

Where do I go from here?
How do I find out which of my lib.a are the problems?
What techniques can be used to further work out what is preventing my SO from loading?
Is there a way to turn on verbosity in debugging? 
Are there any command line apps that can be used to verify the integrity of my APK and SO?
What other things could be causing this problem?

Please advise.

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html  use how-to to go step by step

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  However, I'm actively porting a framework with lots of library dependencies.  I've been able to get the samples up and running.  What I'm asking for is general strategies for resolving unable to load exception.  At this point I've discovered ldd and will be seeing if that helps.

Comment: Discovered readelf -d which looks to show dependencies in a specific manner.

Comment: @JasonKing Were you able to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: The marakana link is dead, try this: http://web.archive.org/web/20130303012243/http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error messages, it was caused because my native lib uses a non-system library (ie one not in .../usr/lib), in my case gnustl_shared. You have to load any such libraries first by creating a static code block in Java:

```
System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
```

The library in your app that can't be loaded is libRb.so. Work out which other libraries it needs to be linked with and load them first.